# SQL Queries Using JavaFX application

Tags: mysql, javafx

I am working on a sql query coming from a javafx program that I cannot get to work correctly.
Example:
Table 1 - order

column titles:

`customer_id`  INT REFERENCES `customer`(`id`),

`employee_id`  INT REFERENCES `employee`(`id`),

`order_date`   DATE NOT NULL,

`order_status` VARCHAR(10)

Table 2 - order detail

Column titles

`order_id`   INT NOT NULL REFERENCES `order`(`id`),

`product_id` INT NOT NULL REFERENCES `product`(`id`),

`quantity`   INT NOT NULL,

I need the ID from table 1 to populate  order_id in table two while the rest of the column values are provided by java code.

String sql2 = "INSERT INTO `order_detail` (`order_id`,`product_id`,`quantity`) VALUES(?,?,?)";
String sql3 = "SELECT MAX(`id`) FROM `order`";

```
        pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql2, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        pstmt.setString(1, sql3);
        pstmt.setInt(2, pid);
        pstmt.setInt(3, quantity);

         pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

I think the issue is both how I have sql3 used and the sql statement - when I do some testing and enter a value into psmt.setString(1, 23) for example, the statement is inserted into the database.

Comment: `pstmt.setString(1, sql3);` What are you doing here? Are you trying to insert the string `"SELECT MAX(id) FROM order"` into your database?

Comment: It looks like you need to actually query the database for sql3. Then you need to use the value that is returned in the query for sql2.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to insert the value returned from the SELECT statement into the database. I will try querying the database for that value. Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't use Max(id) to get the latest order ID... SQL can return the ID it inserted from an insert statement.